# I am getting this error when compiling my program. Operator " + " cannot be applied to operands of "System.Random" and "System.Random"

Tags: c#, mono, operators, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I am trying to generate random numbers for math problems. When the program is compiled the error Operator " + " cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Random' and 'System.Random. I really dont know how to fix this error.

```
            Random num1 = new Random(0);                
            Random num2 =new Random(0); 
            int rand; 


            Console.Write("What is");
            Console.Write(num1);
            Console.Write( " - ");
            Console.Write( num2);
            Console.Write( "?");
            int answer = Console.Read();

                    if (num1 + num2 == answer) ERROR {
                    Console.Write(" Your are Correct!\n");
                    correctCount++;

                }
                    else
                    Console.Write( "Your answer is wrong" );
                    Console.Write(num1);
                    Console.Write(" + ");
                    Console.Write(num2);
                    Console.Write("should be ");
                    Console.Write(num1 + num2); ERROR
                    count++;
                }
            }

            }
        }
```

Now i am able to compile the program without any errors, but it is not generating any numbers. Does anyone see what i may have donwe wrong.

```
               using System;
               using System.Collections.Generic;
               using System.Linq;
               using System.Text;

               using Android.App;
               using Android.Content;
               using Android.OS;
               using Android.Runtime;
               using Android.Views;
               using Android.Widget;
             namespace Jagtutor
             {

[Activity(Label = "Addition")]
public class AdditionsActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Second);

        var label = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.screen3Label);
        label.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("ModuleData") ?? "Data not available";

        {
        int correctCount = 0;
        int count = 0;

             while (count < 10);
            {
                Random gen = new Random();
                int num1 = gen.Next();
                int num2 = gen.Next(); 


            Console.Write("What is");
            Console.Write(num1);
            Console.Write( " - ");
            Console.Write( num2);
            Console.Write( "?");
            int answer = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (num1 + num2 == answer) {
                    Console.Write(" Your are Correct!\n");
                    correctCount++;

                }
                    else
                    Console.Write( "Your answer is wrong" );
                    Console.Write(num1);
                    Console.Write(" + ");
                    Console.Write(num2);
                    Console.Write("should be ");
                    Console.Write(num1 + num2);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            }
        }
```

}

Comment: Besides the answers to your actual question (which the error message already told you pretty clearly), `Console.Read` does not do what you think it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx. You probably want: `int answer = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`.

Answer (score 7):

You misunderstood the way `Random` is used: it is not a *number*, it is a class that can be used to *generate random numbers*.

Try this:

```
// Make a generator
Random gen = new Random();
// Now we can use our generator to make new random numbers like this:
int num1 = gen.Next();       
int num2 = gen.Next();
```

Every time you call `gen.Next()` you get a new random number. If you would like the sequence of random numbers to be repeatable, pass a number (any number) to the constructor of the `Random`. Beware that every time you run your program the result will stay the same.

Comment: You can also limit the size of the random numbers by using an overload of `Next` that takes parameters.

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few issues with the code snippet you pasted. I'd suggest (if you haven't already) investing in a decent beginning C# book. Generating random numbers, in fact, is one of the most popular "example programs" you find in those kinds of books. However, to get you started, here's some key points:

1. When you paste sample code to a site like this, make sure it is a [short, self-contained, ***correct*** example](http://sscce.org/). Even if we fix the compiler error in your code, there are several other issues with it, including unbalanced and/or missing braces. Start simple and build your example up until you get the error, then paste that code. Note that a good 75% of the time this will help you fix the error yourself. For example, if you removed the lines of code that did not compile, and just ran the first part, it would print out `"What is System.Random - System.Random?"`, which should give you a pretty clear idea that your `num1` and `num2` are not what you thought they were.
2. As the rest of the answers here have pointed out, you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the C# [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class works. (Don't feel bad, computer-generated "random numbers" make no sense to anyone until someone explains them to you.) The solution provided in those answers is correct: `Random` is a random number *generator*, and you need to call one of the `Next` functions on your instance to get an integer from it. Also, you usually will not want multiple instances of `Random` unless you actually want to produce the same random sequence more than once. The MSDN article has a very thorough example.
3. While not "wrong" per-se, you're not being very efficient with your console output.  Console's read and write functions operate entirely on `string` objects, and they have built-in [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) capabilities. For example, your first few lines of code could be rewritten as:

   ```
   var random = new Random();
   var x = random.Next();
   var y = random.Next();

   Console.Write("What is {0} + {1}? ", x, y);
   ```
4. As I mentioned in my comment, `Console.Read()` is not the correct function to read in complete user input; it returns data a single UTF-16 character at a time. For example, if the user typed in `150` you would get 49, 53, and 48, in that order. Since you presumably want to allow the user to type in more than one digit at a time, you should instead called `Console.ReadLine()`, which returns the entire string, then convert that to an integer using `Int32.Parse()` or some similar function.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add two random generators not random numbers, use this:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random(0);

var num1 = randomGenerator.Next();
var num2 = randomGenerator.Next();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call one of the overloads of Random.Next() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b3ta19y.aspx to get the actual random number.

Comment: Err... this is correct, as far as it goes. Not sure why someone -1.