# Operator `+' cannot be applied to operands of type `int' and `System.Random'

Tags: c#, random

i'm a beginner to c#,so i was trying to make a program that rolls a die for you and the enemy for 10 turns,each turns adding the number of your roll to an overall count and whoever got the largest in the end won,i didn't finish it all the way but this is what i have so far:

```
namespace dfgs
{
   class dice
   {
       public static void Main(String[] args)
       {
           int plsc = 0;
           int aisc = 0;
           int turns = 0;
           Random plrnd = new Random();
           Random airnd = new Random();
           while (turns < 11)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player Roll Is" + Convert.ToInt32(plrnd.Next(6)));
                Console.WriteLine("AI Roll Is" + Convert.ToInt32(airnd.Next(6)));
                plsc = plsc + plrnd;
                aisc = aisc + airnd;
                Console.WriteLine("Type A and hit enter to go again");
                string nxt = Console.ReadLine();
                if (nxt == "A"){
                    turns++;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            
       }   
   } 
}
```

and whenever i try to compile i get the error `Operator +' cannot be applied to operands of type int' and System.Random'`,this error appears twice,i tried changing the type of the random numbers to int but then i got the error messege `Type int' does not contain a definition for Next' and no extension method Next' of type int' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`  i am kinda stuck here,any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:Thank you to everyone who answered, i have managed to make this work,here is the final code,it's not the cleanest but works as intended:

```
namespace dfgs
{
   class die
   {
       public static void Main(String[] args)
       {
           int plsc = 0;
           int aisc = 0;
           int turns = 0;
           Random plrnd = new Random();
           Random airnd = new Random();
           while (turns < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player Roll Is " + Convert.ToInt32(plrnd.Next(6)));
                Console.WriteLine("AI Roll Is " + Convert.ToInt32(airnd.Next(6)));
                plsc = plsc + plrnd.Next(6);
                aisc = aisc + airnd.Next(6);
                Console.WriteLine("Type A and hit enter to go again");
                string nxt = Console.ReadLine();
                if (nxt == "A"){
                    turns++;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
                if (turns == 10){
                    if (plsc > aisc){
                        Console.WriteLine("The Player Has Won,Ai Score: " + aisc + " Player Score: " + plsc);
                    }

                    else if (aisc > plsc){
                        Console.WriteLine("The AI Has Won,Ai Score: " + aisc + " Player Score: " + plsc);
                    }
                    break;
                    
                }
               
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
       }   
   } 
}
```

Comment: You forgot to put the `.Next()` bit after `plrnd` and `airnd`

Comment: You really don't need more than one instance of `Random`.  Use the same instance to get all of your random numbers.  As you have it set up, it's possible that both `plrnd` and `airnd` will emit the same sequence of random numbers (which is probably not what you want).  Another pro tip: calling those variables something like `playerRandom` (or `playerRand` or `playerRng` (where RNG is Random number generator)) only costs a few extra keystrokes, but will make your code make more sense the next time you look at it: "I wonder what what I meant by air-N-D"

Comment: searching for the title results in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321246/i-am-getting-this-error-when-compiling-my-program-operator-cannot-be-appl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
plsc = plsc + plrnd;
```

In this code, `plrnd` is not a number. Instead, it's a generator for producing numbers. You must tell the generator to give you the next number, as you did on the line above:

```
plrnd.Next(6)
```

Moreover, you likely need to change the code above to save the results of each call in variables so you can use that same value to both show to the user and increment the total count.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to save the random int you get from the Random, rather than trying to calculate number, plus a random_number_generator_machine - which, in some real world terms would be like asking someone "what is your age, divided by a cheese sandwich?"..

```
            var plroll = plrnd.Next(6);
            var airoll = airnd.Next(6);
            Console.WriteLine("Player Roll Is" + plroll);
            Console.WriteLine("AI Roll Is" + airoll));
            plsc = plsc + plroll;
            aisc = aisc + airoll;
```

You don't need a Random for the player and a Random for the computer; one Random could adequately generate for both, btw:

```
       int plsc = 0;
       int aisc = 0;
       int turns = 0;
       Random r = new Random();
       while (turns < 11)
       {
            var plroll = r.Next(6);
            var airoll = r.Next(6);
            Console.WriteLine("Player Roll Is" + plroll);
            Console.WriteLine("AI Roll Is" + airoll));
            plsc = plsc + plroll;
            aisc = aisc + airoll;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.If i only use one random,it seems to me it would be much more work to differentiate between the player score and ai score,but i could be wrong.

Comment: I made an edit to demonstrate only needing one Random

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use the result of the roll multiple times, *start* by assigning the results to a variable for later use:

```
while (turns < 11)
{
    // roll dies, store results in local variable
    var plRoll = plrnd.Next(6);
    var aiRoll = airnd.Next(6);

    // then reuse the variables
    Console.WriteLine("Player Roll Is " + plRoll);
    Console.WriteLine("AI Roll Is " + aiRoll);
    plsc = plsc + plRoll;
    aisc = aisc + aiRoll;
    Console.WriteLine("Type A and hit enter to go again");
    string nxt = Console.ReadLine();
    if (nxt == "A"){
        turns++;
    }
    else {
        // remember to break out if the player doesn't want to continue
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a built in value data type in C#. `Random` is a class object. The `+` operator does not know how to add an `int` data type and a `Random` class object together. What you probably meant to do is to use the `Next()` method, which *does* return an `int`. Also, you only want to `new` up the `Random` class one time. Consider using this code instead:

```
namespace dfgs
{
   class dice
   {
       public static void Main(String[] args)
       {
           Random rnd = new Random();
           int plsc = 0;
           int aisc = 0;
           int turns = 0;
           int plrnd = rnd.Next(6);
           int airnd = rnd.Next(6);
          while (turns < 11)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player Roll Is" + plrnd);
                Console.WriteLine("AI Roll Is" + airnd);
                plsc = plsc + plrnd;
                aisc = aisc + airnd;
                Console.WriteLine("Type A and hit enter to go again");
                string nxt = Console.ReadLine();
                if (nxt == "A"){
                    turns++;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        
       }   
   } 
}
```